# JOIN is duplicating GROUP_CONCAT content

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
projetos.id_projeto, 
projetos.projeto AS projeto, 
projetos.descricao AS descricao, 
projetos.thumb, 
GROUP_CONCAT(imagens.imagem ORDER BY imagens.ordem ASC) AS imagens, 
GROUP_CONCAT(imagens.largura ORDER BY imagens.ordem ASC) AS larguras, 
GROUP_CONCAT(imagens.altura ORDER BY imagens.ordem ASC) AS alturas, 
GROUP_CONCAT(premios.id_premio) AS premio 
FROM projetos 
JOIN imagens ON projetos.id_projeto = imagens.id_projeto
JOIN premios ON premios.id_projeto = projetos.id_projeto 
WHERE projetos.id_projeto = 44
GROUP BY projetos.id_projeto
```

But it's duplicates the imagens, larguras, alturas and premio content.

I tryed to use `DISTINCT` inside GROUP_CONCAT. But some widths values are equal and I need one width for each image.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c3756f/5

Comment: Can you provide some data to help us ? Thanks !

Comment: first of all according to the query you posted you don't need that `prizes` table in this query at all :-) and 2nd thing replace `JOIN` with `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: @Alex I add prizes to grab all information I need in one query. What do you suggest? I add LEFT JOIN but the output is the same.

Comment: so show us raw data and your result as well as expected result, and we can help you. if you need information from table `prizes` you should use at lease one field from that table when  `SELECT ...`

Comment: @Alex Sorry Alex. I edit the code.

Comment: @marcelo2605 and raw data of tables?

Comment: @Alex How can I export raw data from phpmyadmin?

Comment: copy-paste :-) or export

Comment: did you apply LEFT JOIN?

Comment: @Alex Yeah. Nothing happens.

Comment: I need to see data then, because query seems being correct

Comment: @Alex I created a SQLFiddle with my problem: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c3756f/5

Comment: @marcelo2605 Can't you just use `DISTINCT` with the `GROUP_CONCAT`? - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c3756f/11

Comment: @bluefeet No, because the numbers of itens in largura (width) is not equal the number of itens in imagens (images).

Comment: @marcelo2605 so you have 2 records in `premios`  id = 16 and id = 17 which one should be taken? what is your expectations and why?

Comment: @marcelo2605 Your data in the fiddle doesn't match the output above or the desired result, please edit your question to match the data from the fiddle.

Comment: @marcelo2605 so what about my question? what should we do with 16 and 17?

Comment: @ALex 16 and 17 is prizes id associated with this project. I need both numbers.

Comment: but what images should be used for each one?

Comment: @Alex Imagens (images) is independent of premios (prizes). What I need is each imagem output has a largura (width) and a altura (height). If I apply DISTINCT for all GROUP_CONCAT, I will return the correct number of images, but the wrog number of altura and largura, because some altura and largura values are equals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here it is](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c3756f/17):

```
SELECT 
projetos.id_projeto, 
projetos.projeto AS projeto, 
projetos.descricao AS descricao, 
projetos.thumb, 

imgs.*,

prem.premio

FROM projetos 

JOIN (
  SELECT id_projeto,
    GROUP_CONCAT(imagem ) AS imagens, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(largura ) AS larguras, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(altura ) AS alturas
  FROM imagens
  GROUP BY id_projeto
  ) imgs ON projetos.id_projeto = imgs.id_projeto
JOIN (
  SELECT id_projeto,
    GROUP_CONCAT(premios.id_premio) AS premio 
  FROM premios 
  GROUP BY id_projeto
  ) as prem ON prem.id_projeto = projetos.id_projeto 

WHERE projetos.id_projeto = 44

GROUP BY projetos.id_projeto ;
```